# How to deploy watch app in device?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

**Device Information**

**iOS Version: 8.4**

**WatchOS Version: 1.0.1**

When I try to deploy demo app in watch it shows device ineligible. Please someone give me some clues!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you register your Apple Watch UUID in your developer center?
2. Are you using Xcode 6 or 7?
3. Did you generate the correct provisioning profiles?